# Extending valuation to function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Serre's *Algebraic groups* and I was not able to understand a definition he gave there. Let $(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ be a smooth projective curve. One defines 
$$
 \mathscr{O}_{X,p} = \varinjlim_{p\in U \subseteq X} \mathscr{O}_X(U)
$$
and
$$
k(X) = \varinjlim_{U \subseteq X} \mathscr{O}_X(U)
$$
which induces injections
$$
\mathscr{O}_X(X) \to \mathscr{O}_{X,p} \to k(X).
$$
Since $X$ is smooth $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is a DVR. Let $\nu_p$ be its associated valuation. How is this valuation extended to $k(X)$? Serre says that if $f = ut^n$ where $u$ is an invertible element in $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ and $t$ a uniformizing parameter of $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ then $\nu_p(f) = n$. However, this is only defining $\nu_p$ for elements in $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ not $k(X)$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal O_{X, p}$ is an integral domain, and $k(X)$ is its field of fractions.

Therefore, seeing that all elements in $\mathcal O_{X, p}$ can be written in the form $u t^n$ with $u$ a unit and $n \geq 0$, it must be the case that all elements in $k(X)$ can be written in the form $u t^n$ with $n$ *positive or negative*.

So for a given $f \in k(X)$, $v_p(f)$ can take any value in $\mathbb Z \cup \{ \infty \}$. Such an $f$ is contained in $\mathcal O_{X, p}$ if and only if $v_p(f) \geq 0$.

Comment: why is $k(X)$ the field of fractions of $\mathscr O_{X,p}$?

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas Pick an open _affine_ subset $V  \subset X$ containing the point $p$. Suppose that the coordinate ring on $V$ is $A$, and suppose that the point $p$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $A$. Then $\mathcal O_X(V) = A$, and $\mathcal O_{X, p} = A_{\mathfrak p}$, and $k(X) = A_{(0)}$ (where $(0)$ denotes the zero ideal in $A$). We have the inclusions $A \subset A_{\mathfrak p} \subset A_{(0)} = \rm{Frac}(A)$. And it's just a standard result in algebra that $\rm{Frac}(A_{\mathfrak p}) = \rm {Frac}(A)$.